# Azure ADB2C Single Sign Out W/ Azure AD as Identity Provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, msal.js

I have a React SPA which uses `msal`. I have configured Azure AD as Identity Provider for my AADB2C. I can signIn/signOut and other operations.

If my user signs out off my application, I want to also sign out of my Identity Provider. I looked a bit into this matter [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#sign-out), [3](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/57608), [4](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md#front-channel-logout), [5](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-react-samples/react-router-sample).

At this moment, I use `msal`'s `logoutRedirect` method.

```js
const url = new URL(AadEndSessionEndpoint);
url.searchParams.append('post_logout_redirect_uri', SPAUrl);
instance.logoutRedirect({
  postLogoutRedirectUri: url.toString()
});
```

What happens, after my user signs out of my AADB2C, he gets redirected to the AAD `end_session_endpoint`. I can sign out there as well, but my user gets stuck there. Even though I'm passing the `post_logout_redirect_uri` query parameter to go back to my app, it ignores it.

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an [RP Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#RPLogout) in OpenID Connect terms, meaning you need to also send the `id_token_hint` query parameter.

I can also confirm that sending both query string parameters logs out successfully for my Azure developer account:

```js
url.searchParams.append('post_logout_redirect_uri', SPAUrl);
url.searchParams.append('id_token_hint', myIdToken);
```

I think the MSAL library requires you to use [getAccount](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md#logoutredirect) instead:

```
const account = msalInstance.getAccount();
await msalInstance.logoutRedirect({
    account,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://contoso.com/loggedOut"
});
```

**UPDATE**

Your code above is not right - the post logout redirect URI should be that of your own app - I expect the library already knows the end session endpoint location - so just do this:

```
instance.logoutRedirect({
  postLogoutRedirectUri: SPAUrl
});
```

At the same time it is worth being aware that the full standards based GET URL should look like this. With the knowledge of the expected URL you can check that you are sending the right request via browser tools:

```
https://[AadEndSessionEndpoint]?id_token_hint=[myIdToken]&post_logout_redirect_uri=[SPAUrl]
```

The end session endpoint should be a value such as this by the way:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/7f071fbc-8bf2-4e61-bb48-dabd8e2f5b5a/oauth2/v2.0/logout

Comment: I looked into this but I couldn't figure out a way to get the `id_token_hint` out of `msal`.

Comment: Try the above getAccount option - interested to see if that works ...

Comment: Okay, now I got a bit confused. So I need to edit my question. The thing is that I'm doing exactly what you've shown in the second example (if you don't specify the account, I think it gets the active one, or the first from `getAccounts()`). The thing is that, I want to sign out of my Identity Provider, in this case AAD. The method that I tried is that I passed as `post_logout_redirect_uri` a URL to my AAD, and in the second URL I have another `post_logout_redirect_uri`. Probably I don't get something right, but from what I've read, I need to sign out of two places.